# How to make text fadeout in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fadeout

I'm trying to develop a clone of the online web app Patatap and I want to display the instructions for 5 seconds to the user when they load the page and then have the page fade out.

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>

<script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.font = "regular 40px Questrial";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText("Press 'a-z' keys to play a tune!", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

    var fade_out = function() {
        $("#context").fadeOut().empty();
    }

    setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

</script>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why my text isn't displaying and fading out, I'm new to Javascript so any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Please add that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#context").fadeOut() is looking for an element with an id of 'context'.  There's no such element.  Your canvas has an id of 'myCanvas'.  So try $("#myCanvas").fadeOut().  Also, at least in a test, the background is white so drawing text in white doesn't show up.  What's below works, with the fillStyle changed to red:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>

<script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.font = "regular 40px Questrial";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText("Press 'a-z' keys to play a tune!", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

    var fade_out = function() {
        $("#myCanvas").fadeOut();
    }

    setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

</script>

</body>
```